# how to fix 'resource not found' when trying to download file in spring boot REST API?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to spring framework and REST, and now trying to migrate REST from jersey to spring boot 2.1
The controller works fine with jax-rs, however, I don't want to use jax-rs in spring boot. So, I tried spring Mvc and I get 'resource not found' error. Please I'd really appreciate any help.

I tried this

```
@GetMapping(value ="/generic/download_file/{path:[^\\.+]*}", consumes ="application/vnd.X-FileContent")
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile(@PathVariable("path") String filePath){

        String actualFilePath = "";

        try {

            actualFilePath = filePath.replaceAll("\\/", "\\\\");

            File file = new File(actualFilePath);

            if (file.exists()) {

                return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"").body(file);

            } else {

                return errorHandling.errorResponseFactory("1.0.0", Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1], "",
                        RecommendedSolution.UseValidDirectoryPath, "File not exist.");

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ActionLog.writeLog("program_library_v510", "1.0.0", "Exception occur during gettig generic package file",
                    ActionLogType.DebugLog);
            ActionLog.writeLog("program_library_v510", "1.0.0", "Exception occur during getting generic package file",
                    ActionLogType.ErrorLog);

            return errorHandling.errorResponseFactory("1.0.0", Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1], "",
                    RecommendedSolution.UnexpectedErrorMsg, "");
        }
    }
```

> 2019-01-07 17:17:23.930  INFO 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
>   2019-01-07 17:17:23.947 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/packages/download_file/D:/xfolder/test.txt", paramete
>   rs={}
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.002 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/
>   resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.006 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.007 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.015 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.029 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServ
>   letRequest)
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.077 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [applic
>   ation/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.078 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Jan 07 17:17:24 SGT 2019, status=40
>   4, error=Not Found, message=No message available, path=/packages/download_file/D:/xfolder/test.txt}]
>   2019-01-07 17:17:24.146 DEBUG 13664 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404

Comment: Please add the stack trace to your resource not found, if you have it. I think that adding a little more detail on the exact scenario you're running would also help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect two things here. Let me clarify this.

1. What is the API url you are calling?
   `/generic/download_file/{path:[^\\.+]*}` or `/packages/download_file/D:/xfolder/test.txt`

both are looks different. Please see *generic* and *packages*

2. The better way to pass filenames in URL is using `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`

   @GetMapping(value ="/generic/download_file/", consumes ="application/vnd.X-FileContent")
       public ResponseEntity downloadFile(@RequestParam("path") String filePath){

Comment: You are right @Satz. I intended to call
**packages/generic/download_file/{path:[^\\.+]*}**  Now I have changed the
url and also use the **RequestParam** and the result is still same  Thank
for feedback  The base url for this controller class is **/packages**

   

         `@GetMapping(value ="/generic/download_file/**/{path:[^\\.+]*}", consumes ="application/vnd.X-FileContent")  
     public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile(@RequestParam("path") String filePath)  {}`